# My fault or Rails fault? Suspected error in de-pluralize name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not a native english speaker (nor writer ;), but :

```
class BloodGas < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blood_gases
end
```

and now, try to do this in console :

```
Patient.find(1).blood_gases
```

it should return Relation object, but instead I've got

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Patient::BloodGase
```

which puts a light on, I believe, inflector failure here... 
Or, more probably, my fault.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I did some more research, and :

```
"blood_gases".classify => "BloodGase"

"blood_gases".singularize => "blood_gase"
```

I've put :

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'blood_gas', 'blood_gases'
end
```

in /config/initializers/inflections.rb, but nothing promising happens...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `class_name` option when declaring your `belongs_to`. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-class-name)

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blood_gases, class_name: 'BloodGas'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails do not know how to inflect all the English words. In some cases you need to tell it what is plural version of given word. In rails you have congig/initializers/inflector.rb file. Just add:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.irregular 'gas', 'gases'
end
```

and restart the server.

UPDATE:

your inflector didn't make a difference as rails is trying to guess singular name from plural, your definition just tell it how to go from singular to plural. Weird, but true.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Rails bug. You can add your own inflection (http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/09/inflector-rails-pluralization/), or specify an associated model name, like that:

> has_many :blood_gases, class_name: 'BloodGas'